# Decoding string to UTF-8 (URL/Percent-encoding strings)

Tags: python, string, encoding, urlencode

In my Python 3 program I've come across weirdly encoded strings such as "abol%C3%A2t" (abolât) and "%C5%93ufs" (œufs). I get them from WiktionaryParser.

I've only found ways to encode it to UTF-8 for quoted-printable strings, which is not the case here. How can I change a string from "%C3%A9vitables" to "évitables"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These strings are [Percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Use the [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) module to decode them:

```
import urllib.parse

s = "%C5%93ufs"
s = urllib.parse.unquote(s)
```